# If $a,b$ are self-adjoint operators, $a \leq b$, and $ab=ba$, then $f(a)\leq f(b)$ for every increasing continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $a,b$ are self-adjoint operators, $a \leq b$, and $ab=ba$, then $f(a)\leq f(b)$ for every increasing continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is an exercise in GTM 96, maybe using continuous function calculus.

Comment: Operators defined in a Hilbert space?(which one?) what does $a\leq b$ mean?

Comment: @VictorGustavoMay: Typically this means that $b-a$ is positive definite.

Comment: $C*-algebra$. $a\leq b$ means $b-a$ is positive operater, that is $\sigma(b-a) \subseteq [0,+\infty)$

Comment: Got it for $a \le b$, but $f(a) \le f(b)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The notion of $a\leq b$ does not depend on the algebra because the spectrum does not, so we can consider the unital $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ generated by $a$ and $b$. By Gelfand theory, there is a $\ast$-isomorphism from $A$ to $C(X)$ for some compact $X$. Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ denote the images of $a$ and $b$ under $\Phi$. Since spectra are preserved under $\ast$-isomorphisms, we have $\phi\leq \psi$, and it is not hard to check that this is equivalent to $\phi(x)\leq \psi(x)$ for all $x\in X$. Now the monotonicity of $f$ comes into play to imply $f(\phi(x))\leq f(\psi(x))$ for all $x\in X$. Pull all of this back under $\Phi$ to get $f(a)\leq f(b)$.

Or, informally: You can work with commuting self-adjoint operators as if they were real-valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly true for all continuous convex functions. The key observation is to equate the problem to vector majorization and then use the theorem of Hardy, Littlewood, and Polya (see, for example, [Marshall and Olkin](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-68276-1), Sec.4.B.1).

Here's a sketch of the proof: Since $a,b$ are self-adjoint and $\left[ a,b \right] =0$, they can be simultaneously diagonalized (using the spectral theorem). Then, consider a spectral decomposition of the form, $a = \sum_{j} \lambda_{j} P_{j}, b = \sum_{j} \alpha_{j} P_{j}$ (note the same orthogonal projections in their expansion). Also, note that $f(a) = \sum_j f(\lambda_{j}) P_{j}$. Then, written in this basis, we have, $a \leq b \implies \mathrm{diag}(a-b) \leq 0$. That is, $a_{j} \leq b_{j} ~~\forall j \in \{ 1,2, \cdots,n \}$ (where $n$ is the dimension of the operator). As a consequence of which, we have, $a \prec_{w} b$ ([weak vector majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization)). Then, using the theorem of Hardy, Littlewood, and Polya, we have, $\sum_{j} f(\lambda_{j}) \leq \sum_{j} f(\alpha_{j})$ for all continuous increasing convex functions.

Comment: I do not understand this equality $f(a) = \sum_j f(\lambda_j)P_j$ ?

Comment: It is essentially a way to [extend a scalar function to a matrix function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Extending_scalar_function_to_matrix_functions). For diagonalizable matrices (say, for example, coming from self-adjoint operators), applying the function on the matrix amounts to applying the function on the eigenvalues (in a basis where the matrix is diagonal) and then transforming back to the original basis. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am just confused by the notation $f(a)$ I guess. Thank you for explaining further.

Comment: The claim in the OP has nothing to do with convexity, vector majorization and the like. Instead, it follows almost immediately from the spectral theorem and the monotonicity of $f$.